# ASP.Net Core WebAPI Authorization Policy for User or Admin

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt

I have a controller that returns data about users. I want to set the authorization such that an admin can access this controller and retrieve data for any user, and a non-admin user can access the controller and retrieve data for themselves.

I've ruled out using `[Authorize (Roles = "Admin")]` because this means users can't get their own data. So I've inserted the following logic into the controller action:

```
var userId = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name).Value;
var roles = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindAll(ClaimTypes.Role);

var query = roles.Select(r => r.Value).Contains("Admin");

Customer customer =await _context.Customers.FindAsync(id);

if (!(customer.EmailAddress == userId || query))
 return Unauthorized();
```

This is roughly equivalent to [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23227252/269035), but for ASP.Net Core rather than MVC.

My question is, is there a way to do this with an Authorization Policy? Adding the RequireRole check is straightforward and covered in the [MS Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-2.2#policy-based-role-checks) as well as countless blogs, but I couldn't find or figure out a way to use a policy to check that the data the user is trying to access is their own.

I'm sure this isn't an uncommon requirement, is there a way to do this, or is what I'm currently doing OK? The only other approach I could think of was to have two separate endpoints, but both options seem inelegant.

Comment: User return his/her data , admin return all users' information . They are two different features and you can use two different functions . What if admin wants to only return his own information ?

Comment: User return their data, user is an admin and wants to return only their own data. Ok so they hit endpoint, give me data for user X. Is the user requesting the information user X? Or are they an admin? If either are true, return the data. The same logic applies and the question still stands - can this be done with an authorisation policy?

Comment: The alternative (which may be what you are suggesting) is to have one endpoint annotated with [Authorize(Roles=“Admin”)] which gives data for any user, and another which just requires a logged in user, which doesn’t allow you to specify which user you want data for, but will rather look up the user in the claim and return that user’s data. Is that what you’re suggesting? As per my question this seems inelegant and seems to violate the DRY principle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The policy is for authorization , but either Admin or A normal user can access the controller , they are all authorized .

That is your custom logic to determine which data should be returned , that is nothing related to authorization . If you insist on using policy , you can put the logic to handler but that is nothing change when logic is in controller :

```
public class CustomerHandler : AuthorizationHandler<CustomerRequirement>
{
    IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor = null;

    public CustomerHandler(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
                                               CustomerRequirement requirement)
    {

        HttpContext httpContext = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;

        //your logic 

        httpContext.Items["message"] = "ownData";

        context.Succeed(requirement);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

And read in controller so that you can know whether read his own data or all users' data :

```
var message = HttpContext.Items["message"];
```

In my option ,set two endpoints/function in your web api , one for admin , one for user is the clean way . In addition , that is your client app's responsibility to determine that current user wants to return his own data or all user's data  . That seems not quite correct to send request to web api and let api to determine by logic . Webapi should include the clean functions/endpoint to map each request from client .

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. Two comments - "The policy is for authorization , but either Admin or A normal user can access the controller , they are all authorized". I get what you're saying here, and when coupled with "In my option ,set two endpoints/function in your web api , one for admin , one for user is the clean way" I understand your suggestion to be authorisation should be to access the endpoint, not to access data. This answers my question and is one of the options proposed in my question.

Comment: My other comment - "In addition , that is your client app's responsibility to determine that current user wants to return his own data or all user's data . That seems not quite correct to send request to web api and let api to determine by logic . Webapi should include the clean functions/endpoint to map each request from client ." Rest assured, the client app does this. However, I don't think it is good design to have the security entirely within the client. The API which provides access to the data should determine that the request is appropriately authorised as well.

Comment: So you can try set two functions on web api side and use policy authorization to make the admin one should access with admin role .